# Android two dimensional ArrayList empty after filling it

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an OpenGL application, where I fill a two dimensional int List with data, I also Logging the size every time I put data in it. It works grate, there is 236 row. But after I call the method later in the Log it gives me back that the size is 0.
Here is how the structur looks like:

Main.java

```
...
onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    if (first == true) {
        // the data comes from another method
        myList.setData(x, y); // I send the the data for the List
                          // and also log the List size, which at the end is 236
        first = false;
    }

    myList.check(); // It just Logs the List size, which gives back 0
}
...
```

List.java

```
private List<int[]> dataS = new ArrayList<int[]>();

public void setData(int x, int y) {
    dataS.add(new int[] { x, y });
    Log.i("size", "size: " + dataS.size());
}

public void check() {
    Log.i("check", "check: " + dataS.size());
}
```

I just can't understand what is the problem with it, hope someone can help me.

**Whole code:**

Main.java

```
public class Main extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer {

public void drawGame(GL10 gl) {
    if (firstGameFrame == true) {
        tMap.setMap();
        firstGameFrame = false;
    }

    collision.check();
}   
}
```

Map.java

```
public class Map {

public void setMap() {

    // map1 is an int map1[][] = {{1,0,1}, {1,1,1}, {0,0,1}}; - of course there are more data in it

    for (int z = 0; z < map1.length; z++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < map1[z].length; x++) {
                if (map1[z][x] == 1) {
                    collision.getWall((x*2) - 23, (z * 2) - 27);
                }
            }
        }
}
}
```

Collision.java

```
public class Collision {

private List<Integer[]> wallCoord = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();

public void getWall(int x, int y) {
    wallCoord.add(new Integer[] { x, y });
    Log.i("getwall", "getwall " + x + " " + y + " size " + wallCoord.size());       
}

public void check() {
    Log.i("coords", "size: " + wallCoord.size());
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Main.collision.getWall((x*2) - 23, (z * 2) - 27);? in Map.java class..

Comment: My comment are under your answer, thank you again ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Without your code, I can just help this, just declare

```
private List<int[]> dataS = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

**as a globally**,

and then use **dataS** through out your class.. and make sure you **never initialized dataS** again anywhere.

I think you are using different collision class object in Map.java and Main.java file, You are set the value using collision object from Map.java class and checking it size with Main's collision class.(If am not wrong).

Comment: The same, when I fill it then the size comes back with the value of 236, but on check it's 0.

Comment: Okay, a moment, I will just cut out what not needed in there.

Comment: There you are, just say if a need put more (the Map and Collision.java are just simple classes).

Comment: I understand what you saying, but actually the ArrayList comes from the Collision file, so it should not matter where I initialize the class, or I am wrong? Maybe you have right, but it would be a bit strange for me.
Or can you write some code what you think should work (if you have of course)?

Comment: OK, you have right! I just called the collision.check in my Map class, and now it gives back the right size. Any idea how can I just reach the correct size in the Main.java?

Comment: Thank you, it works now, I not called the Main.collision.getWall in Map, but the map.collision.check in Main and now the size is 236 all the time. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome buddy, just for right code format, In main.java class when you creat a Map.java class's constructor just pass the collision object in that constructor and in Map.java just use that collision object's reference.. Happy Coding.. :-)

Comment: Yes, I will do it, and to the coding will be happy too, because I can now move on :)